# Easily pickable locks - false advertising to negligence?

Tags: negligence, false-advertising

How do lock manufacturers (padlocks, deadbolts, etc) get away with advertising that their locks are high security or even unpickable, when those locks can be picked open in seconds?  Isnt this false advertising?  I find it impossible to believe that they dont know how easily their locks can be bypassed.  Wouldnt that be negligence?

If you arent familiar with what I am discussing, search for [LockPickingLawyer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCm9K6rby98W8JigLoZOh6FQ) on YouTube to see how easily security devices can be bypassed.  I dont actually know if he is a lawyer, nor does he discuss the legal aspects if he is.  Some of his videos might actually shock you.  For example, he shows how a gun safe can be opened with a plastic spoon, something even a toddler could do.

While I am in the US, I am open to all thoughts.

Comment: I'd suggest your question not be so negative and accusative and presuppose such marketing is negligence. The core question is "What standards apply to the security of locks, particularly those advertised as high security?"

Comment: It doesn't seem like this question actually contains a legitimate legal question.

Comment: *"a gun safe can be opened with a plastic spoon, something even a toddler could do."* Do they show a toddler opening a safe with just a plastic spoon? [UK legislation](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5a7a1638ed915d6d99f5d0d7/security_leaflet.pdf) states: "Lock mechanisms should be on the inside of the cabinet. The lock should contain at least 5 levers to BS 3621 standard or equivalent. Alternatively, good quality hardened padlocks and staples should be fitted to the cabinet". But UK doesn't have a casual attitude to guns, and there are specific storage requirements.

Comment: @WeatherVane Before assuming, you might want to understand that the US has specific gun safe standards promulgated nationwide [because of California](https://oag.ca.gov/firearms/gunsafe).

Comment: I see clearly discernible and indeed quite interesting legal questions to be answered here.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect major manufacturers would hesitate to make claims like "unpickable". What they are more likely to say is "never picked".

As for "high security", I think the courts are liable to treat this as "sellers' puff" whenever padlocks and similar are concerned.

It's worth bearing in mind that lockpicking isn't a common skill, and carrying a set of lockpicks outdoors is liable to treated similar to carrying a jemmy bar, and attract deep suspicion of "going equipped to steal".

If a lock requires some practised skill and special tooling to pick, it is secure by that definition.

Comment: Also note that in some countries, the mere *possession* of lockpicks is a crime, and not even locksmiths may own them - e.g. Japan.